# Implementing an Event Handler in C++

Tags: c++, event-handling, eventhandler

I have always defined my event handlers in the following way:

```
// A.h
class A
{
public:

  A();
  void someMethod();
  void onEvent(void (*callback)(char *, int));
private:
  typedef void (*MyEvent)(char *, int);
  MyEvent _on_update_callback;
};

// A.cpp
void A::someMethod(){
  if(condition){
    if(NULL != _on_update_callback){
      _on_update_callback(&"some message", 42);
    }
  }
}

void A::onEvent(void (*callback)(char *, int)){
  if(NULL != callback){
    _on_update_callback = callback;
  }
}
```

And I used it from the main app in the following way:

```
// main.cpp
#include "A.h"

A a;
int main(void){
  a.onEvent(&eventHandler);
}

void eventHandler(char *text, int code){
  // so something
}
```

Now I need to define an event listener of A from the Class B (instead of the main application).

```
// B.h
#include "A.h"
class B
{
public:
  B();
private:
  A _a;
  void _onEvent(char *text, int code);
};

// B.cpp

B::B(){
  _a.onEvent(&_onEvent);
}

void B::_onEvent(char *text, int code){
  // do something here
}
```

But I get the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'A::onEvent(void (B::*)(char*,
>   int))' note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void
>   (B::*)(char*, int)' to 'void (*)(char*, int)'

Comment: A non-static member function is not synonymous with a regular function. Ask yourself this: Which `B` object shall be the lucky receiver of that method you wish to fire? See a problem? Short version: `void (*callback)(char *, int)` and `void (B::*callback)(char*,int)` are not compatible. The former is a pointer-to-function, the latter a pointer to member function of `B`.

Comment: `&"some message"`: removed the `&`. Here it doesn't compile with `&`. `B()` should be `B::B()`. And `eventHandler` is not member of `B`so `&B::eventHandler` is wrong, it should be `&eventHandler`.

Comment: @WhozCraig, what you say makes a lot of sense. I'm now using templates since I don't know the type of class that will be using my onEvent method:

template<class T>
void onEvent(T* objectPtr, void (T::*memberPtr)(char *, int));

The problem now is that I don't know how to store a reference to (objectPtr->*memberPtr)() to use it later when the event is risen?